# Import error when running pyinstaller app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-imaging-library

I have written a Python app which makes use of:

```
from PIL import Image
```

I want to distribute a packed version of this application so that whoever uses it does not need to install all the dependencies.

For that I have used `pyinstaller`, without much success.
I run:

> pyinstaller --onefile image_download.py

and it does not complain. However, when I run the application, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 26, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "/home/ic/twitter-project/build/image_download/out00-PYZ.pyz/PIL.PngImagePlugin", line 40, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "/home/ic/twitter-project/build/image_download/out00-PYZ.pyz/PIL.Image", line 63, in 
>   ImportError: cannot import name _imaging

I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Python 2.7
- pyinstaller 2.1
- PIL.VERSION 1.1.7 (although I thought I had installed Pillow 2.8.1)

The script works fine running as `python image_download.py`, but pyinstaller is not being able to import _imaging, for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try adding `import _imaging` to the top of image_download.py and rebuild your executable ... sometimes it misses weird hidden imports its probably importing it like `import("_imaging")` or something somewhere

Comment: No luck, no such import. I have tried `import PIL._imaging` and several other combinations with no luck.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154849/wxpython-pyinstaller-fails-with-no-module-named-core/32418327#32418327

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I could not use `pyinstaller` for this, since I could not fix the import problem.

I managed to build a standalone executable with `Nuitka` and `bbfreeze`, though, so in case anyone runs into the same problem: it is worth trying other tools.