# Runnable exe error after using pyinstaller to convert from python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to convert a python file to an exe file to run in another computer which not install python and library. I used pyinstaller and its success to make an exe file. But, when I run it(.exe) an error appears:
[image]

In my function, the error in this line:

```
pyautogui.click()
```

The function mouse movement `pyautogui.moveTo(536, 49, 2, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)`work ok but stuck and waring error at `pyautogui.click()`.
So, is the reason for the error caused by pyautogui lib? And have any idea to fix it? I using python 3.5 and as I know have only pyinstaller work with.

Comment: Duplicate, question because this related to "Pyinstaller" (How to follow  `symlink` on module _core ?)

Comment: @dsgdfg please give me the link, thank you

Comment: @dsgdfg And i don'nt understand in one lib pyautogui, the fuction `moveTo` pretty run but the fuction `click` is not?

Comment: API call procedure include a `DLL` or `_core` library. You want access system resource with this but your missing point how to handle your app_core_libs from os ! Asking a lot user [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154849/wxpython-pyinstaller-fails-with-no-module-named-core) and this error only "your macine haven't any idea about a software building(sys)". Some libraries required compile on your machine (Not DLL import), You can't build directly  a app if include a `Objective-C` contents(External). `Mouse click function` need access system framework but can't do that wit

Comment: (wit = with) pure python. We talking now RAM access and finding `class` or `subclass`. Windows and Linux got different requirements, i don't use windows for building an exe/app(so haven't any idea), but on linux need check `LSB`, `gcc_LSB` don't  install `pyinstaller` without `build` command because you can't be sure which got a bug !